# get a sub-list of a list based on multiple parameters in Java

Tags: java, collections, grouping

I have a list of objects. Each object has a level attribute (int 1, 2 or 3), a City attribute ("New York", "Milan", "London") and generic String FamilyID.
The number of objects in the list is random.
I need to create a sub-list (or any other collection/data structure) which is made of the first objects in the list with any combination of Level and City (I don't care about the FamilyID).

Hope to make my request clearer with an example:

```
InitialList: [1, Milan, ID1][1, London, ID1][1, Milan, ID5][2, Lodon, ID1][2, London, ID6],[3, New York, ID2]

ExpectedOutput: [1, Milan, ID1][1, London, ID1][2, London, ID1][3, New York, ID2]
```

The output collection is a list of the first object with any combination of (level, City).

Comment: Do you mean a sub-list as in `List.subList()`, i.e. backed by the original list or just a filtered copy of the original list? If the latter, what problem are you facing? Filtering a list and creating a new one shouldn't be that hard.

Comment: You are probably right, it shouldn't be that hard. I just started working with OOP and I am struggling quite a bit :). I should mention I know how to do it the "C way", I am looking for a smarter way to do it using Java features.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `streams` with `Collectors` in this case. It will be something like this:

```
initialList.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(City::key, city -> city, (f, s) -> f))
```

Full code example:

```
    public class Stack {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<City> initialList = List.of(new City(1, "Milan", "ID1"),
                new City(1, "London", "ID1"),
                new City(1, "Milan", "ID5"),
                new City(2, "London", "ID1"),
                new City(2, "London", "ID6"),
                new City(3, "New York", "ID2"));

        final ArrayList<City> expectedOutput = new ArrayList<>(initialList.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(City::key, city -> city, (f, s) -> f)).values());

        System.out.println(expectedOutput);
    }


    private static class City {

        private final long level;
        private final String city;
        private final String family;

        public City(long level, String city, String family) {
            this.level = level;
            this.city = city;
            this.family = family;
        }

        public String key() {
            return level + "_" + city;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return new StringJoiner(", ", City.class.getSimpleName() + "[", "]")
                    .add("level=" + level)
                    .add("city='" + city + "'")
                    .add("family='" + family + "'")
                    .toString();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to write a customized comparator here based on the following pseudo logic:

1. if city is same among city lists, include only first city in the List(ignore second array)
2. if level is same and cities are different, include both level and city may be in descending order(of strings) only for the combination of level and city.
3. increment the level and for the incremented level, once-again do comparison of level and city same as you did in steps 1 and 2.
4. For String comparison, you can use the API, string1.compareTo(string2) and return whether the first letter is lesser, same or greater than based on negative, zero or positive value returned by compareTo method.
5. The New-List is then a Filtered List like the output you want.